# C - Structure with different amount of members / array size known at compile time

Tags: arrays, c, struct, macros, typedef

My Problem is the following, i hope someone can help me pls or knows a better way to do it:

The Platform is an embedded system with only static memory, so everything has to be known at compile time, no heap memory or memory management exists.

I have to design structs. The structs represent IO Adapters, their data is stuff like the configuration, pointers where data should read/write, variables needed for read/write operations etc..
Functions accept pointers to their specific IO Adapter struct and then do the read/write operations with the data/variables form the struct.
My Goal is to design the structs as similar as possible.

All Structures Should have a Status struct. This should be like this:

```
typedef struct ChannelStatusS ChannelStatusS;

struct ChannelStatusS{
    const int size;
    int entry[];
};


typedef struct StatusS StatusS;

struct StatusS{
    const int size; 
    int general[];
    ChannelStatusS channel[];
};
```

I know this is not possible, since [0] arrays can only be at the end of structs and i can not in C99 initilize the struct with a variable size:

```
ChannelStatusS channelstatus = {
          .size = 5, 
          .entry = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

This is illegal without compiler extension.

They all need the same status_structure / hold the status information in the same way, so that i only need one function to get the status.

Can someone pls tell me, what is the best way to do this?

The IO structs look like this then:

```
typedef struct ExampleS ExampleS;
struct ExampleS {

        // Some Variables 
    const char_t device_name[20];
    const bool_t simultaneous_update_supported;
    const int bit_resolution; // 12
    const bool use_raw_data;
    const int IO_BUFfER_SIMULTANEOUS_ADR;
        
        // Some specific Structs, that hold const or variable data needed
    ExampleDataS channel[ES753_NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS];
    ExampleRegisterDataS input_register[ES753_NUMBER_OF_CHANNELS];

    // INTERNAL DOSENT NEED TO BE SET
        // Other Variables, that are similar for all Structs and only differ in Size
    StatusS status;
    InternalVariablesS vars;
        
        // Struct with functions pointers
    FunctionsPointerS f;
};
```

If anyone has any ideas / resources about the best way to approach the problem with similarity / identicality for the IO structs, pls let me know.

The Solutions i thought about:

1. No Status struct at all, just a int array and a int size as memeber variables, array size is defined with #define for each Adapter (needs to be defined anyway).
2. Some Macro that defines a Status struct with the needed sizes. Similar to this Solution

"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74381285/c-initialize-custom-array-size-in-struct-at-compile-time/74387468#74387468"

He said that you should take a step back and simplify the problem tho, and I dont have any other idea than using just a int arry?

Also when using the Macro i cant use a function anymore that only gets a StatusS pointer. I would need a individual function for each status struct.

3. Declaring the arrays first and have the structure hold pointers to the array.

If anyone knows of another solution pls let me know.

Comment: First time I see something like inverse Hungarian notation (that one uses prefixes instead of suffices). Recommend dropping that habit, only spoils your identifiers for no benefit.

Comment: @Aconcagua thank you, i didnt know that is bad practis

Comment: Could you use pointer members instead of array members?

Comment: Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/PPbsrxYo1) perhaps?

Comment: And with pointer members you could use compound literal arrays as the initializers for the pointers, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7xP1bcT6T).

Comment: @Aconcagua and /@IanAbbott thanks very much, yeah that should certanly be possible. This will all be part of a libary and someone else has to initilize the structures later. Would you consider it bad style if the array declaration and channel info declaration is one Macro?

Comment: That depends... Usually you avoid macros, they typically hide information and/or make code less readable. But as always there are exceptions. So ask yourself: Is the code *more readable* with or without the macro (*not*: more convenient on writing). If so, then you might go with them.

Comment: @IanAbbott thank you, but in the first comment of this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/74381285/22282363 it says i cant use it with just C99.. sry i didnt mention i have only C99

Comment: @Aconcagua alright thank you, i guess i will try both options then and choose

Comment: You missed a point: @IanAbbott changed your arrays to pointers, other than in the question you refer to – and designated initialisers have been available in C99 as well (whereas such initialisation with arrays, as in the question, isn't possible still today). To see yourself, follow Ian's link and add `-std=c99` to the compiler options ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua /@IanAbbott oh damn nice thanks a lot, i guess i will use this then since it fits perfectly for my use case :)

Comment: @IanAbbott thank you,  if you dont mind post your comment as answer pls so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to the problem is to replace the flexible array members with pointer members like this:

```
typedef struct ChannelStatusS ChannelStatusS;

struct ChannelStatusS{
    const int size;
    int *entry;
};

typedef struct StatusS StatusS;

struct StatusS{
    const int size; 
    int *general;
    ChannelStatusS *channel;
};
```

A pointer member can be initialized to point to an array. If the `struct` object is being initialized statically, then prior to C99 there would need to be a statically allocated array somewhere so that the pointer can be initialized to point to the initial element of that array (or possibly to some other element of the array). That could look something like this:

```
static int some_chan_0_entries[5] = {0};
static int some_chan_1_entries[3] = {0};

static ChannelStatusS some_chans[2] = {
    {
        .size = 5,
        .entry = some_chan_0_entries,
    },
    {
        .size = 3,
        .entry = some_chan_1_entries,
    },
};

static int some_general[2] = {0};

static StatusS some_status = {
    .size = 2,
    .general = some_general,
    .channel = some_chans,
};
```

With C99, those named arrays may be replaced with *compound literals*. For example, the named arrays in the code above could be replaced with compound literals as follows:

```
static StatusS some_status = {
    .size = 2,
    .general = (int[2]){0},
    .channel = (ChannelStatusS[2]){
        {
            .size = 5,
            .entry = (int[5]){0},
        },
        {
            .size = 3,
            .entry = (int[3]){0},
        },
    },
};
```

The compound literal approach should use about the same amount of storage as the using named arrays. The only difference in the amount of storage will the amount of unnamed padding between compound literals. Using named arrays may also introduce unnamed padding between the named arrays, but the order in which they are declared could be adjusted by the programmer to try and minimise the amount of padding.

One downside of using pointers instead of arrays is that extra memory is required to store the pointer.

Another downside is that there is less flexibility in the use of type qualifiers. For example, in `static const ChannelStatusS some_const_channel = { /* initializers here */ };`, the `some_const_channel.entry` member will be a constant pointer, but will point to a non-constant `int`. The only way to point to a constant `int` would be to declare the member as `const int *entry`, but then it cannot be used to point to a non-constant `int`. A possible workaround would be to use a union of a qualified pointer and an unqualified pointer, such as the following:

```
struct ChannelStatusS{
    const int size;
    union {
        int *entry;
        const int *const_entry;
    } u;
};
```

Then the initializer would need to initialize either `.u.entry` or `.u.const_entry` as appropriate. For C11 onwards, the union could be changed to an anonymous union:

```
struct ChannelStatusS{
    const int size;
    union {
        int *entry;
        const int *const_entry;
    };
};
```

and the initializer could initialize `.entry` or `.const_entry` as appropriate. However, OP is stuck with using C99.

In either case, any code accessing the array pointed to by the `entry` member would need to be aware of whether the array is actually `const` or not.

Comment: thank you very much, especially for the indept explanation :)